# cocoapods 0.38.2 post_install hook can't update my preprocessor macros?

Tags: cocoapods, post-install

I added a configuration (adhoc) for my Xcode Project(assume the name is Flurry) and I want to add a `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` to that configuration like DEBUG.I did that    by pro_install hook.I added the following code :

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if config.name == "Adhoc"
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] <<  "ADHOC"
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] <<  "ADHOC=1"
        end
    end
end
```

end

Because I use the cocoapods 0.38.2,So I need to use `pods_project` instead of `project`.

The Code works well on the targets that generated by cocoapods,like the AFNetworking, Pods-Flurry and all the third-party frameworks. But it didn't do any change to my project ,Flurry.So the preprocessor marco **ADHOC** didn't not working when I use the following code:

```
#ifdef ADHOC
NSLog(@"do something here");
#endif
```

So , How can I add a preprocessor marco the my adhoc configuration by using post_install hook.

BTW,the code below work on older version,like 0.37.1:

There is only one difference pods_project and project

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if config.name == "Adhoc"
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] <<  "ADHOC"
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] <<  "ADHOC=1"
        end
    end
end
```

end